# HTTPsendRequest is very slow

Tags: ios, swift, http-get

In this code I get a string from a website and show it on a label. 
Show the string on the label is really slow! about 10 seconds. 
But when printing the string on console println (date) is immediate. 
How can I fix this?

```
    func HTTPsendRequest(request: NSMutableURLRequest,
    callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                callback("", error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                callback(NSString(data: data,encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, nil)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
}

func HTTPGet(url: String, callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    HTTPsendRequest(request, callback) }


@IBAction func myButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    HTTPGet("http://www.mywebsite.com/test.txt") { (data: String, error: String?) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            self.myLabel.text=error
            println(error)
        } else {
            self.myLabel.text=data
            println(data)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSURLSession` completion blocks do not run on the main queue. But, you must run UI updates on the main thread, so you should dispatch your `callback` there, e.g.:

```
func HTTPsendRequest(request: NSMutableURLRequest, callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            if (error != nil) {
                callback("", error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                callback(NSString(data: data,encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, nil)
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```